# How to scale_fill_gradient my ggplot bar graph using a third variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a bar graph made that graphs countries along the x-axis and Cost along the y-axis. I want to fill the bins with a colour depending on the countries HDI score. Highest HDI score = white, Lowest HDI score = red.

Here is my code so far, I get a nice plot, but no gradient fill??

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=reorder(dat$Country, -dat$COE_millions), y=dat$COE_millions), fill=dat$HDI) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=5, colour="black", angle=90),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, colour="black", vjust=-0.1),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, colour="black", vjust=+0.35)
  )+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="snow1", mid="red", high="red4", guide="colorbar", space = "Lab", midpoint=0.6)
```

My data looks like this for example;

```
| Country | Cost   | HDI   |
| USA     | 100    | 0.9   |
| Can     | 60     | 0.8   |
| Aus     | 50     | 0.7   |
```

Comment: try moving fill inside your call to aes...i.e., aes(x=Country,  y=COE_millions, fill=HDI)

Comment: Don't use `$` subsetting in `aes`; just use the bare variable name instead.